Try external access, why I got connection time out?
I want to access my postgre DB by external. But when I try to access, I got connection time out. I don't have idea what's the problem..
I've configured the PostgreSQL config file, set up inbound firewall rules, configured a static IP, and even set up port forwarding. When I try to connect using telnet command in the CMD or add connection with DBeaver, using external IP and specified port, I get a connection time out.
When I use the netstat command, it shows that PostgreSQL is listening on 0.0.0.0:5432.
Is there anything I missed?

Your firewall or other network settings are incorrect. Nobody can say more than that with the information here.

Thnks for reply. I will recheck my configurations..
